association_rules() Positional argument problem
While forming association rule I'm trying to use association_rules from mlxtend.frequent_patterns. But getting error stating that I'm missing one positional argument named 'num_itemsets'.
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori, association_rules
frequent_items = apriori(group_df, min_support=0.05, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_items, metric='confidence',min_threshold=0.7)

and encountered the following error
association_rules() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num_itemsets'
I'm not finding any document where mentioned about this argument. Still I modified my code blindly as follows
rules = association_rules(frequent_items, metric='confidence',min_threshold=0.7, num_itemsets=2)
It worked. But I don't know what is happening, I'm looking for assistance to know about this.

This started to happen due to changes in the mlxtend library version 0.23.2. It is still unclear whether it is a bug or a feature (open issue). So there are two options to fix that error:

Downgrade mlxtend package to version 0.23.1 (if we assume it is a bug) or
Add add num_itemsets parameter: rules = association_rules(frequent_items, num_itemsets=len(group_df), metric='confidence',min_threshold=0.7, num_itemsets=2). Here I set the parameter to len(group_df) since docstring is saying it should be to "Number of transactions in original input data".


I got the same error in 0.23.3 and downgraded to 0.23.1 and it works now.

I am of the opinion that this is a bug.
This MR, which intended to better support datasets with missing values, added num_itemsets as a required argument. Its docstring defines it as the "number of transactions in original input data".
Note that there are two DataFrames in this function's arguments: a required one called df and an optional one called df_orig. The fact that num_itemsets is required could indicate that it is supposed to contain the size of df, but its docstring could indicate that it is supposed to contain the size of df_orig. So to me there's some ambiguity as to what this argument actually represents, and reading the rest of the PR didn't help.
Either way, the number of itemsets can be derived from the DataFrames themselves! So I don't see why this argument should even exist, much less why it should be required.
If this argument truly represents the number of transactions in the original input data, that should be derived from whichever DataFrame this argument represents the size of. If it represents something else, it should be renamed to something less ambiguous and probably made optional.
